# Function that transforms a string of upvote counts into an array of numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

What is the best possible way to create a function that transforms a string of upvote counts into an array of numbers. Each `k` represents a thousand.

```
transformUpvotes("6.8k 13.5k") ➞ [6800, 13500]

transformUpvotes("5.5k 8.9k 32") ➞ [5500, 8900, 32]

transformUpvotes("20.3k 3.8k 7.7k 992") ➞ [20300, 3800, 7700, 992]
```

Return the upvotes as an array.

Now i tried to do this myself with or without regex, the pattern i used was this `/\.\d(k)/g`
I first converted the string into a javascript array using `array.split(' ');` but i don't know how to replace the `k` with `zeroes` properly so that the `k` after floating point get two zeroes and a k without floating point get three zeroes.

Comment: Check if the number ends with "k" and if it does then multiply it by 1000...

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty stupid of me, solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function transformUpvotes(upvotes) {
  return upvotes.split(" ").map(x => {
    parsed = parseFloat(x);
    return x.endsWith("k") ? parsed * 1000 : parsed;
  });
}
```

Comment: return upvotes.split(" ").map(x => parseFloat(x)*(x.endsWith("k") ? 1000 : 1)); // a bit smaller